# opengl tiny rendering glitch, need help & tips

Tags: c++, opengl, freeglut

here is my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <gl/freeglut.h>
#include <gl/GL.h>
#include <gl/GLU.h>
#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

typedef unsigned short us;
typedef unsigned char uc;

bool *keystates = new bool[256];
bool *skeystates= new bool[256];
uc dir_m[8][2]={
    { 0, 1 },
    { 0,-1 },
    { -1,0 },
    { 1,0 },
    { 1,1},
    { 1,-1 },
    { -1,-1 },
    { -1,1 }
};

us totalbots=15;

float zoomlvl=-70.f;
float camx=0.f,camy=0.f;

struct bot_data{
    float x,y,z;
    float r,g,b;
    float size; //    "radius" of the square
    us coold;
    us age;
    us trans:5;
    us dir:3,fac:2;
    bot_data(void);
    void move(void);
    void deliver(us bot);
};
struct bool_data{
    bool ch:1,ch2:1;
};

bot_data::bot_data(void){
    size=0.25f;
    fac=rand()%4;
    switch(fac){
    case 0:x=10.f,y=10.f,z=0.f;
        r=1.0f,g=0.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    case 1:x=-10.f,y=-10.f,z=0.f;
        r=0.0f,g=0.f,b=1.f;
        break;
    case 2:x=-10.f,y=10.f,z=0.f;
        r=1.0f,g=1.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    case 3:x=10.f,y=-10.f,z=0.f;
        r=0.0f,g=1.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    }
    coold=0;
    trans=0;
    age=0;
    dir=rand()%8;
}

bot_data *cubers=new bot_data[65536];
bool_data *bools=new bool_data;

void bot_data::move(void){
    float move=size/10.f;
    switch(dir){
    case 0:y+=move;
        break;
    case 1:y-=move;
        break;
    case 2:x-=move;
        break;
    case 3:x+=move;
        break;
    case 4:x+=move;
        y+=move;
        break;
    case 5:x+=move;
        y-=move;
        break;
    case 6:y-=move;
        x-=move;
        break;
    case 7:y+=move;
        x-=move;
        break;
    }
}
void bot_data::deliver(us bot){
    age=-10;
    totalbots+=3;
    float tmp=size-(size/4.f);
    size=0.25f;
    x-=size;
    y+=size;
    for(uc i=1;i<=3;i++){
        cubers[totalbots-i].fac=fac;
        switch(fac){
        case 0:cubers[totalbots-i].r=1.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=0.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        case 1:cubers[totalbots-i].r=0.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=0.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=1.f;
            break;
        case 2:cubers[totalbots-i].r=1.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=1.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        case 3:cubers[totalbots-i].r=0.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=1.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        }
        cubers[totalbots-i].coold=coold;
        cubers[totalbots-i].size=size;
        switch(i){
        case 1:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y-size*2;
            break;
        case 2:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x+size*2;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y;
            break;
        case 3:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x+size*2;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y-size*2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void initkeys(void){
    for(uc i=0;i<255;i++){
        keystates[i]=false;
        skeystates[i]=false;
    }
}
void p_keys(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    keystates[key]=true;
}
void keyup(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    keystates[key]=false;
}
void sp_keys(int key, int x, int y){
    skeystates[key]=true;
}
void skeyup(int key, int x, int y){
    skeystates[key]=false;
}
void key_func(void){
    if (keystates['z']){
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_UP])zoomlvl+=1.f;
        else if (skeystates[GLUT_KEY_DOWN])zoomlvl-=1.f;
        if(zoomlvl<-100.0f)zoomlvl=-100.f;
        else if(zoomlvl>-5.f)zoomlvl=-5.f;
    }
    else{
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_UP])camy-=1.f;
        else if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_DOWN])camy+=1.f;
    }
    if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_LEFT])camx+=1.f;
    else if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_RIGHT])camx-=1.f;
}
void render_p(us bot){
    glColor3f(cubers[bot].r,cubers[bot].g,cubers[bot].b);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(cubers[bot].size,cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(cubers[bot].size,-cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(-cubers[bot].size,-cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(-cubers[bot].size,cubers[bot].size);
    glEnd();
}
void process_cubers(void){
    for(us i=0;i<totalbots;i++){
        //glPushMatrix();
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(cubers[i].x,cubers[i].y,cubers[i].z);
        if(cubers[i].coold==0){
            cubers[i].move();
            cubers[i].trans++;
            if(cubers[i].trans==20){
                cubers[i].trans=0;
                cubers[i].coold=50;
                if(cubers[i].age<100){
                    cubers[i].size+=0.025f;
                }
                else if(cubers[i].age==150){
                    cubers[i].deliver(i);
                }
                cubers[i].dir=rand()%8;
                cubers[i].age+=10;
            }
        }
        else cubers[i].coold--;
        render_p(i);
        //glPopMatrix();
    }
}
void display(void){
    key_func();
    glClearColor(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f,1.f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(camx,camy,zoomlvl);
    process_cubers();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    SDL_Delay(1000/30);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void resize(int width,int height){
    glViewport(0,0,(GLsizei)width,(GLsizei)height);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(60,(GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height,1.f,100.f);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    initkeys();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0, 0); 
    glutCreateWindow ("opengl 1");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutIdleFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(p_keys);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyup);
    glutSpecialFunc(sp_keys);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(skeyup);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

it renders a certain amount of said squares that move each certain intervals. their move distance is their size. each time they move they grow in size until they reach the size limit (1.f in radius in this case) after a certain amount of moves (15 in this case) the square will split into 4 smaller squares and FILLING OUT THE EXACT SPACE its precursor occupied, that means it is supposed to look completely seamless..the problem is instead, i get this split second tear & glitch-looking rendering after the square splits, but other than that i found no other problems.

what i  suspect is perhaps i missed some gl function i was supposed to call around the time i am rendering the new 3 squares (the splitting occurs by adding 3 new squares, and shrinking the current one to a quarter of its size, then adjusting all the squres.)

Comment: GLUT xor SDL: Pick one *and only one* framework.  If you want to frame-limit in GLUT use `glutTimerFunc()` to re-arm the timer and kick off a `glutPostRedisplay()`.

Comment: good idea, i was really cheap with implementing a frame rate when i made this, so i went with sdl. i will change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

typedef unsigned short us;
typedef unsigned char uc;

bool *keystates = new bool[256];
bool *skeystates= new bool[256];
uc dir_m[8][2]=
{
    { 0, 1 },
    { 0,-1 },
    { -1,0 },
    { 1,0 },
    { 1,1},
    { 1,-1 },
    { -1,-1 },
    { -1,1 }
};

us totalbots=15;

float zoomlvl=-70.f;
float camx=0.f,camy=0.f;

struct bot_data
{
    float x,y,z;
    float r,g,b;
    float size; //    "radius" of the square
    us coold;
    us age;
    us trans:5;
    us dir:3,fac:2;
    bot_data(void);
    void move(void);
    void deliver(us bot);
};

struct bool_data
{
    bool ch:1,ch2:1;
};

bot_data::bot_data(void)
{
    size=0.25f;
    fac=rand()%4;
    switch(fac){
    case 0:x=10.f,y=10.f,z=0.f;
        r=1.0f,g=0.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    case 1:x=-10.f,y=-10.f,z=0.f;
        r=0.0f,g=0.f,b=1.f;
        break;
    case 2:x=-10.f,y=10.f,z=0.f;
        r=1.0f,g=1.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    case 3:x=10.f,y=-10.f,z=0.f;
        r=0.0f,g=1.f,b=0.f;
        break;
    }
    coold=0;
    trans=0;
    age=0;
    dir=rand()%8;
}

bot_data *cubers=new bot_data[65536];
bool_data *bools=new bool_data;

void bot_data::move(void)
{
    float move=size/10.f;
    switch(dir){
    case 0:y+=move;
        break;
    case 1:y-=move;
        break;
    case 2:x-=move;
        break;
    case 3:x+=move;
        break;
    case 4:x+=move;
        y+=move;
        break;
    case 5:x+=move;
        y-=move;
        break;
    case 6:y-=move;
        x-=move;
        break;
    case 7:y+=move;
        x-=move;
        break;
    }
}

void bot_data::deliver(us bot)
{
    age=-10;
    totalbots+=3;
    float tmp=size-(size/4.f);
    size=0.25f;
    x-=size;
    y+=size;
    for(uc i=1;i<=3;i++){
        cubers[totalbots-i].fac=fac;
        switch(fac){
        case 0:cubers[totalbots-i].r=1.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=0.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        case 1:cubers[totalbots-i].r=0.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=0.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=1.f;
            break;
        case 2:cubers[totalbots-i].r=1.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=1.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        case 3:cubers[totalbots-i].r=0.0f,cubers[totalbots-i].g=1.f,cubers[totalbots-i].b=0.f;
            break;
        }
        cubers[totalbots-i].coold=coold;
        cubers[totalbots-i].size=size;
        switch(i){
        case 1:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y-size*2;
            break;
        case 2:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x+size*2;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y;
            break;
        case 3:cubers[totalbots-i].x=x+size*2;
            cubers[totalbots-i].y=y-size*2;
            break;
        }
    }
}

void initkeys(void)
{
    for(uc i=0;i<255;i++){
        keystates[i]=false;
        skeystates[i]=false;
    }
}

void p_keys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    keystates[key]=true;
}

void keyup(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    keystates[key]=false;
}

void sp_keys(int key, int x, int y)
{
    skeystates[key]=true;
}

void skeyup(int key, int x, int y)
{
    skeystates[key]=false;
}

void key_func(void)
{
    if (keystates['z'])
    {
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_UP])zoomlvl+=1.f;
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_DOWN])zoomlvl-=1.f;
        if(zoomlvl<-100.0f)zoomlvl=-100.f;
        if(zoomlvl>-5.f)zoomlvl=-5.f;
    }
    else
    {
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_UP])camy-=1.f;
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_DOWN])camy+=1.f;
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_LEFT])camx+=1.f;
        if(skeystates[GLUT_KEY_RIGHT])camx-=1.f;
    }
}

void render_p(us bot)
{
    glColor3f(cubers[bot].r,cubers[bot].g,cubers[bot].b);
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex2f(cubers[bot].size,cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(cubers[bot].size,-cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(-cubers[bot].size,-cubers[bot].size);
    glVertex2f(-cubers[bot].size,cubers[bot].size);
    glEnd();
}

void process_cubers(void)
{
    for(us i=0;i<totalbots;i++){
        if(cubers[i].coold==0){
            cubers[i].move();
            cubers[i].trans++;
            if(cubers[i].trans==20){
                cubers[i].trans=0;
                cubers[i].coold=50;
                if(cubers[i].age<100){
                    cubers[i].size+=0.025f;
                }
                else if(cubers[i].age==150){
                    cubers[i].deliver(i);
                }
                cubers[i].dir=rand()%8;
                cubers[i].age+=10;
            }
        }
        else cubers[i].coold--;
    }

    for(us i=0;i<totalbots;i++)
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(cubers[i].x,cubers[i].y,cubers[i].z);
        render_p(i);
        glPopMatrix();
    }
}

void display(void)
{
    key_func();
    glClearColor(0.6f,0.6f,0.6f,1.f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    double w = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH );
    double h = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT );
    gluPerspective(60, w / h,1.f,100.f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(camx,camy,zoomlvl);

    process_cubers();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void timer(int extra)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(33, timer, 0);
}

int main (int argc, char **argv) 
{
    initkeys();
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode (GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize (640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition (0, 0); 
    glutCreateWindow ("opengl 1");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutKeyboardFunc(p_keys);
    glutKeyboardUpFunc(keyup);
    glutSpecialFunc(sp_keys);
    glutSpecialUpFunc(skeyup);
    glutTimerFunc(0, timer, 0);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

You were drawing in your simulation loop.  This splits that into two loops, sim then draw.

Comment: also, for future reference, i tried doing the same with my code. it appears that all that had to be done was to move the glpushmatrix to the end of the loop instead of the very beginning, producing the same results.

Answer (score 0):

The way graphics rendering works (OpenGL or otherwise) is that it only guarantees a "nice" seam between two triangles that are "exactly" aligned along some edge if you render them as part of the same triangle strip, the same (vertex buffer, index buffer) model pair, or some other construct that groups triangles into a single render unit.

When you render a "quad," you are really rendering a 2-triangle triangle strip, so the seam between the two triangles looks nice.

When you render two seperate quads that are aligned along some edge, the edge can look bad. Anti-aliasing can help to fix the problem a little bit, but ultimately you need to use a single render unit if you want to get rid of the tearing along seams.

The figure shows four quads (eight triangles) being rendered in a grid. The diagonals are within quads so there isn't any tearing, but the since the quads are all rendered separately there is tearing along their seams.

[image: rendering four quads]

Comment: thanks for your response timothy, i understand how quads are rendered but i have a gut feeling you dont understand the issue im experiencing. the problem i have is not with a bad-looking edge, but a short, split second, misposition of the rectangles. in that short period of time, you can see the rectangles all clustered together (more or less, clearly not in the same position, though) and after a frame (maybe? hard to tell) they go to their designated coordinates. to me the rectangle looks perfect when i align them together, the 4 of them, but i think i missed something...